# jFrame new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

Could you please help me with simple program which is executing windows cmd command. By clicking jbutton3 i want to execute code with PING command with parameters set in textboxes but problem is that during the execution whole window freeze. I tried to run new Thread after button click but windows still freeze, could you point me what I am doing wrong?

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{

public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Thread worker = new Thread() 
    {

        public void run() 
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {

                public void run() 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Runtime rt2 = Runtime.getRuntime();

                        String IP2, COUNT;
                        IP2 = jTextField4.getText();
                        COUNT = jTextField3.getText();
                        Process pr = rt2.exec("cmd /c ping -n " + COUNT + " " + IP2);

                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                        String line=null;

                        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                            jTextArea1.append(line + "\n");
                            jTextArea1.repaint();
                            jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        jTextArea1.append("\nCOMPLETED!\n");
                        jTextArea1.repaint();
                        jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());
                        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

                    } 
                    catch(Exception e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                });
            }
        };
    worker.start();
}  

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got a background thread, which immediately creates another Runnable that calls your long-running process is run on the Swing event thread -- the exact place where it shouldn't be run (by passing the Runnable into the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method).

The solution: run long stuff in a background thread that is **not** run in the Swing event thread, and only run Swing code within the event thread.

Read: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: ah so simple, it's working now, thank you :)